# How can I show the whole layout above the SoftKeyBoard

Tags: android

I have a `Layout` wrapped in a `ScrollView`. When the **SoftKeyBoard** is opened, I want the whole layout to be present above the **SoftKeyBoard**.

**From the image below:**

> 1. Initial state
> 2. What I am getting when the SoftKeyBoard is open
> 3. What I want when the SoftKeyBoard is open

[image]

**What I tried:**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

None worked.

Thank You.

Comment: try removing scroll view

Answer (score 0):

use    'android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"'

Comment: Yeah I tried `adjustResize` it didn't work, may be because my layout cannot be re sized.

Comment: try: ´android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"´

Answer (score 0):

try this permission 
  ->android:windowSoftInputMode=" stateAlwaysHidden | adjustPan "

I think it will work.
Thanks.